# going back to first calling activity in other app

Tags: android

this is my scenario:

I have two android apps, in first one an activity say app1_activity1 calls app2_activity1 using intent action filter. then from there i call app2_activity2. my question arises here:
how can i go back to first activity in first app from app2_activity2 i.e: directly from app2_activity2 to app1_activity1

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start it the same way as you started `App2`. The only difference is that you want to make sure that `App1` does not create multiple instances of itself. Same goes probably for `App2`. In order to achieve that you can add

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Docs on `singleTask`

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) about the other modes.

Comment: sorry i didn't quite understand. i started app2 using action filter say: com.packagename.appname.activity_filter_name . now how can i call app1 calling activity. can u give me an example please

Comment: @RezaEN The same way how you started app2 you start app1 again.

Comment: but i dont have any information on calling app1_activity1. i started app2_activity1 using action filter.

Comment: @RezaEN You can pass the package and activity name information from app1 as a extra string in the intent and use that to call it back in app2.

Comment: thanks, but could u give me and illustrating code sample? imagine i have two string variable : app2_packagename and app2_activityName. what to do next

Answer (score 0):

Just call `finish()` in all app2's activities.

Probably starting app2_activity2 with `startActivityForResult` will be more convenient in this case.

Comment: calling finish in app2_activity2 just returns to app2_activity1. and i sometimes just move from app2_activity2 to app2_activity1. and dont want to finish it automatically

Comment: Yes, and then you need to call `finish()` inside app2_activity1. That's the most reliable solution in this case.

Comment: better to say i have a button in app2_activity2 when i hit that i want to go to app1_activity1 directly

Comment: If you started app2_activity2 with `startActivityForResult` you will have the `onActivityResult` callback executed in app2_activity1 after calling `setResult` and `finish` from app2_activity2. You can call `finish` inside the callback then.